# @font-face not working in any browser

Tags: css, fonts, path, font-face, embedding

Not exactly a new topic, I know, but reading through all the @font-face related postings I still can't find an answer to my problem.

I'm new-be so I'm assuming there's a terribly embarrassing major/basic mistake I don't see or some conceptual misunderstanding from mys side.

ANY HELP IS HIGHLY APPRECIATED!

Here's what I have in my style sheet (together with all other style definitions):

```
   @font-face {
    font-family:'CorporateSBQ-Light';
    src:url('/fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.eot');
    src:url('/fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.svg#CorporateSBQ-Light') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    }
    html, body 
    {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    font-family:"CorporateSBQ-Light", Helvetica Light, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#9FAD9E;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

I feel like I have the right path to the right directory and the correct spelling etc. but even after days of trying different paths, re-converting the fonts (in Fontsquirrel and another web-based converter-service) etc., for some reason the desired fonts won't display correctly, wether locally in DM or browsers nor in any browser when uploaded. Instead I'm getting a Helvetica or Arial.

I also tried to give the font a completely different name before converting which simply just converts it back to the original name. Renaming it after converting didn't help either.

The "fonts" folder is placed in the root folder. I tried as well to place the fonts directly in the root folder (without any folder holding them), and I was playing around with "CorporateSBQ-Light" and 'CorporateSBQ-Light' in all thinkable variants – no success.

Thanks!!

Comment: "Helvetica Light" should be surrounded by quotes because it is a font that is defined with more than one word

Comment: Also, try using this @font-face generator kit it has worked for me when I was having trouble: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: It looks quite OK, though I don't know whether it is allowed to specify font-weight in the face. I think you should just define a different face with a different name if you want another weight. See http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/

Comment: Also, a link to your attempts would be nice. You say 'I feel like I have the right path to the right', but knowing is key. Can you see the files being downloaded if you look in the network tab of your development tools? (Chrome, FireBug).

Comment: Here's the solution, just figured it out, must have to do with relative/absolute path, still confused with that:

src:url('../fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light...   
instead of url('/fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light...

Thank you all for your help though. Hope it'll help other people.

Comment: @user1546952 in that case explain the solution as an answer, not a comment, and accept your own answer.  That will make it a lot clearer that the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other style definitions before your font-face definitions?
If not try adding them as the first lines.

I also remember having trouble of that kind, when the fonts were in a different folder than the CSS, maybe this is worth a try, too.

These are the instructions from some fonts i purchased recently, which work fine for me in any browser:

> Upload the fonts into the same folder as your CSS file and copy this
>   code into your CSS:

```
/* first for IE 4–8 */
@font-face {
  font-family: Family-Name;
  src: url("Family-Name.eot");
}

/* then for WOFF-capable browsers */
@font-face {
  font-family: Family-Name;
  src: url("Family-Name.woff") format("woff");
}

/* go on with normal style definitions */
body { 
  font-family: Family-Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may Try

```
 @font-face {
    font-family:'CorporateSBQ-Light';
    src:url('../fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.eot?iefix') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/CorporateSBQ-Light.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    }
```

Comment: src:url('../fonts/ instead of url('/fonts/

Comment: Thanks everybody! And special thnanks to Bumlbe2na for the "Helvetica Light" hint.